# Amazon Red Price

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

On Amazon store there are many prices and I'm trying to get what is referred as Amazon Price that is in red and Large. When I try

```
$pxml = aws_signed_request("com", array("Operation"=>"ItemLookup","ItemId"=>$itemId,"ResponseGroup"=>"Large"), $public_key, $private_key);
$pxml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Price->FormattedPrice;
```

I get a price that's higher than the red price.

If I use

```
$pxml->Items->Item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->FormattedPrice;
```

I get a price lower than the red price that shows up where is say xx new from $5.49 (for example). Does anybody know how to get this value?

Thanks,

Comment: your not providing any logic in your example, just pointers to a nameless API. At the very least, link to the API where these methods reside.

Comment: Chailyan: The api is Amazon Product Advertising Api.

Comment: Api link:     http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/index.html?CHAP_response_elements.html#FormattedPrice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. The prices weren't matching because the items are sold by 3rd party vendors. When the items are sold by Amazon the above outlined method worked fine. From what I gather you can't get the 3rd party price info through Amazon api.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the red price here:

```
$pxml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Price->Amount;
```

Comment: Thank you pguardiario. I checked it out but it returns the same value as:$pxml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Price->FormattedPrice; except unformatted